# Filling in comment replies when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

To append data I am using `parent()` method five times in the code and I think it seems like an ugly way to do this.

```
$("div.commentItem a.showReplies").on("click", function(){
    var jqData = "i am so eE";
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('div.commentItem span.repliesholder').append(jqData);
});
```

Here is the HTML DOM:

```
<div class="commentItem">
    <div class="head">
        <a href="/profile/{{id}}" class="commentator">{{name}}</a> - <span class="date">{{date|timeago}}</span>{{actionLinks}}
        <span class="cmtMsg"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="commentBody">{{content}}</span>
    <span class="repliesholder"></span>
    <a class="showReplies">Show Replies</a> <!-- listen to this click -->
</div>
```

It works just fine, but what should be the best practice?

Comment: can't you work with css selectors?

Comment: i am sorry, i have added the dom structure please take a look

Comment: I voted to reopen per the edit.. but I also cast a downvote, because this post is very very boiled down to a specific issue, making limited room for reviews/answers - consider adding the actual skipped code.

Comment: ok i think i add them as well :D

Comment: Why do you need to use `parent()` at all? Can't you just do `$(this).prev().append(…)`?

Comment: @200_success Good point. I jumped the gun and answered before there was any HTML. You should put that in an answer.

Comment: @Flambino I'm uncomfortable answering because the question is so sketchy. But I also don't want to start another close-open cycle, so I'm hoping that the author will provide clarification.

Comment: @200_success That's fair. I definitely answered too hastily myself, which I shouldn't have. Just wanted to call attention to your comment, because now that there's markup in the question, it looks like a better answer than mine.

Comment: @200_success its more clean and seems better. will give it a try, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery's docs for `.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/): You can specify a selector to find a specific ancestor.

Or you can use the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to get all ancestors, and grab the 5th like so: `$(this).parents().get(4)` (or `.eq(4)` to get a jQuery-wrapped object).

However, the former solution (specifying a selector) is the better solution, since it's the most specific and direct. The latter solution assumes that it'll *always* be the 5th ancestor - whatever the 5th ancestor might be. Not very precise or robust, and it couples your code way too tightly to the markup.

*Edit: This answer was posted before the question contained the markup. See 200_success's answer for a simpler answer given the markup's structure.*

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to use `parent()` at all? Can't you just do `$(this).prev().append(…)`?

Comment: Note that `prev()` also accepts a selector string like `parent()` does, which can make the code more explicit and robust, should the markup's structure change.